# TIMECODE CALCULATION

Tags: video, excel-formula, frame-rate, texel

I attempting to convert frame into timecode based on framerate.

example 1:

framerate is: 25 fps (C1)

video frame is: 145068 (C2)

and a timecode for that is 01:36:42.18

format of the timecode is: HH:MM:SS.FF (hours:minutes:seconds:frame)

-

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can do this. You can either create your own function within Excel that accepts the Video Frame and Frame Rates and returns the TimeCode required, or else you can use some worksheet functions to perform the same calculations.

In each case, you need to divide the Video Frame by the Frame Rate and 3600 (the number of seconds in an hour) to get the Hour part. You then divide the Video Frame Rate by the Frame Rate and 60, and then subtract the previously calculated Hours to get the Minute part. Next, divide the Video Frame by the Frame Rate and subtract the the total number of minutes previously calculated. Finally, get the remainder when the Video Frame is divided by the Frame Rate. Combine all of these together, and you get the answer that you are after.

First the VBA function. Paste this into a new Module:

```
Function fTimeCode(lngFrame As Long, lngFrameRate As Long) As String
    Dim lngHour As Long
    Dim lngMinute As Long
    Dim lngSecond As Long
    lngHour = Int(lngFrame / (lngFrameRate * 60 * 60))
    lngMinute = Int(lngFrame / (lngFrameRate * 60)) - (lngHour * 60)
    lngSecond = Int(lngFrame / lngFrameRate) - (lngHour * 60 * 60) - (lngMinute * 60)
    fTimeCode = Format(lngHour, "00") & ":" & Format(lngMinute, "00") & ":" & Format(lngSecond, "00") & "." & Format(lngFrame Mod lngFrameRate, "00")
End Function
```

You can now use this just like any built-in formula in Excel, so you would type this in a cell in the worksheet:

```
=fTimeCode(C2,C1)
```

And if you just want to use Worksheet functions:

```
=TEXT(INT(C2/(C1*60*60)),"00")&":"&TEXT((INT(C2/(C1*60))-(INT(C2/(C1*60*60)))*60),"00")&":" & TEXT(INT(C2/C1)-(INT(C2/(C1*60))*60),"00")& "." &  TEXT(MOD(C2,C1),"00")
```

Regards,