# How is Powershell converting a number to an int type?

Tags: powershell, casting, integer, rounding

I am trying to create a prototype for a simple timecode (non-drop) program to be later implemented as a class.

I have figured out the math, by following [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859321) helpful answer. One thing that is throwing me off is how PowerShell is choosing to round the float to an integer.

```
$frames     = 111000224
$fps            = 12
[int]$hour  = ($frames / ($fps * 3600))
[int]$min   = ($frames / ($fps * 60)) - ($hour * 60)
[int]$sec   = ($frames / $fps) - ($hour * 3600) - ($min * 60)  # this will be "-1", I have yet to figure out or fix this
$fra        = $frames % $fps

"hours: $hour"
"minutes: $min"
"seconds: $sec"
"frames: $fra"
```

The output I get is

```
hours: 2569
minutes: 27
seconds: -1
frames: 8
```

I am expecting "minutes" to be `26` as shown in this online [Frames to Timecode Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/frames-to-timecode?c=GBP&v=fpses:12,frames:111000224) example but for some reason PowerShell gives me `27`.

Running `[int]("26.3")` returns `26`, while  `[int]("26.7")` will return `27`. I thought PowerShell was merely dropping the decimal here, is that not so?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you could do `[System.Math]::Round(($frames / ($fps * 60)) - ($hour * 60), [System.MidpointRounding]::ToZero)` there to get `26` otherwise it will use the default rounding technique (...By default, the Round method uses the round to nearest even convention.)

Comment: `[Math]::Floor` is simpler in this case. see the linked answer.

Comment: In .NET (and also PowerShell), casting to `[int]` invariably employs _half-to-even midpoint rounding_, so that all of the following yield `2`, for instance:
 `[int] 1.5`, `[int] 2.5`, `[int] 1.8`, `[int] 2.2` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893799/45375) for details.
To _truncate_, i.e. to simply _remove any fractional part_ from a `[double]`, `[float]` or `[decimal]` value, use [`[Math]::Truncate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Truncate).
The result won't be an `[int]`, but you can then simply cast to it; e.g., `[int] [Math]::Truncate(2.5)`